# How to force preview a zip file in ktorrent?

Tags: bittorrent

`ktorrent` only allows previewing (download 1st chunk right?) for audio and video.

What I don't understand: The whole point of previewing is confirming if the file is ok.  So why we can't preview compressed files (zip, rar, 7z etc)? As far I know the file list is on the beginning of the compressed file.

I think actually that it should *always download the 1st chunk for every file*, so we could verify any file we want...

Anyway, I tried looking everywhere like

```
strings $(which ktorrent) |egrep mp3 -i
```

and many other variations also with other files on all the ktorrent packages, but found nothing that could **control what files will be previewable**, I was willing to tweak it.

Any tip?

Should I move to another torrent client? But I very much like `ktorrent`'s options and usability.

Actually, I will "preview" the zip file externally (using a file manager). Trying to open it, if it has the first chunk, will show the file list.

EDIT: I ended up moving to Deluge with Pieces plugin enabled. As soon I downloaded the 1st chunk, the whole file list with size and date was shown at the zip file manager! I copied the torrent and did a "force re-check" what "imported" it on Deluge. Should this be an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Archives are not audio/video container formats (which are often created for streaming purposes and having the beginning of the file is often enough to start playing it) and in many cases you cannot even parse the contents of a compressed file without it being fully downloaded because its table of contents could be spread through the entire file.

Please request this feature from KTorrent maintainers - I guess they could implement it for archive files as well: https://bugs.kde.org/enter_bug.cgi?format=guided&product=ktorrent

Comment: So it is not on the 1st chunk! https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Shahzad_Ahmed16/publication/316682490/figure/fig15/AS:668532127834138@1536401888962/Zip-file-format-I-SQL-Database-Table-In-SQL-database-table-data-is-stored-in-the-form.png

Comment: I was thinking, to preview any file like a zip, an iso (file contents), a jpg (thumbnail) etc. is a more generic thing and would depend on the source server (the computer holding the whole file). May be this question/request should be addressed by bittorrent protocol/team and not ktorrent? I mean, if the other side is not using ktorrent it wont be able to prepare a proper preview, but all torrent clients use bittorrent protocol.

Comment: well.. getting the first chunk would allow be to know the first file details at least! what could be considered a partial preview :)

Comment: Files formats are wildly different and also what you consider to be a "preview" might be different from what other people think. For archives some would say the first file in an archive, for you it's a file listing.

Comment: mmm... you are right, btw I moved to deluge+pieces https://superuser.com/a/884723/631645, but it still not answer the "preview everything requirement" of the question, it is only about chunks...

Comment: btw, I tested, downloading the first chunk of the zip file brought the whole file list tree with size and date info! :), could this mean that moving to deluge+pieces would be the right answer for a zip file at least? if you agree, feel free to add this as an alternative on your answer :)

Comment: For ZIP files specifically, the central directory is at the *end* of the file. Retrieving the first chunk would allow you to reconstruct the list of files whose compressed data is present in that first chunk, but that’s all.

Comment: oh.. well I didnt really pay attention if the last chunk was already there after completing the first chunk! so this means I need the 1st (to let the zip manager at least open the file) and the last chunks (for the file list) to preview a zip file, thx! That is built-in option in deluge even w/o Pieces plugin I think!